# How to know which project template I selected initially?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have created .net core application some days ago. Now I don't remember exactly which template I have selected for the project. What is the way to know the project template selected for any project.
Problem here is when I generate `"Controller with Edit/View using Entity Framework"` the default behavior is it should generate **controller specific folder** in `"Views"` folder but it is not generating that folder.
If I click on any method (`public ActionResult View()`) and try to generate view it is generating view in the controller folder only. It should generate this in **controller specific folder** in "Views" folder.[image: Folder structure]

Comment: can you please show me your project folder structure and config-route file so that i can help you.

Comment: Please pay attention when you choose tags for your questions. [.net] + [core] is wrong when you actually mean [.net-core]

Comment: @KrishnaBankar I have updated the question and added project folder structure. I didn't understand what you mean by config-route please let me know I will add it if necessary.

Comment: @SudhirDehade The same problem happened with me. I just cut this folder with the generated file and pest it inside the views folder even though it worked. you can also try this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can see RouteConfig.cs file is inside App_Start folder.
But it does not have anything that will help to solve your problem.
you can follow my last comment.

The same problem happened with me. I just cut this folder with the generated file and pest it inside the views folder even though it worked. you can also try this

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am working on .net core project. There is no web.config, global.asax, app_start folder.